# Django DetailView template not showing the details

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django web framework from past few days and its pretty awesome. I am learning class based views to display the content. I have created a simple example models `school(name,principal,location)` and `student(name,age,school(foreign key))`. The models are

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# Create a School model with different classes
# School Model with Name,Pricipal & Location
class School(models.Model):

    # Create name,pricipal,location fields for the School
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    # method to pritn the string representation of the class
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create a stduent model of the school
class Student(models.Model):

    # create name,age,school fields for students
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='stduents', 
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # method to print the string representation of stduent class
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My urls.py is

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

# Create a app_name for template tagging
app_name = 'CBV_app'

urlpatterns = [
     path('',views.SchoolListView.as_view(),name='list'),
     path('<int:pk>/',views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')
]
```

Main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from CBV_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.IndexView.as_view()),
    path('CBV_app/',include('CBV_app.urls', namespace='CBV_app'))
]
```

The foreign key in the student model has a **related_name ='students'** which connects with school model. I have registered the models and created the class based views (list and detail views) in `views.py` file. 
The `views.py` file is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import models

# Create your views here.



# create a view using the built in template view
class IndexView(TemplateView):

   # template_name is the class object attribute of class TemplateView
   # Just pass in the html file that need to be displayed
   template_name = 'index.html'


# create a list view class for school inheriting from ListView
class SchoolListView(ListView):


    context_object_name = 'schools'


    # connect this to the created models
    # this provides the models each record in the form of list
    model = models.School


# create a detail view for the school by inheriting the DetailView
class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'school_detail'

    # set the view to the model
    model = models.School
    # point the class attribute template_name to point the detail view

    template_name = 'CBV_app/school_detail.html'
```

And my `student_detail.html` file is

```
{% extends "CBV_app/CBV_app_base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
<p class="display-4">Welcome to school details page</p>
<p class="h3">School details:</p>
<p class="lead">School Id: {{school_detail.id}}</p>
<p class="lead">Name: {{school_detail.name}}</p>
<p class="lead">Principal: {{school_detail.principal}}</p>
<p class="lead">Location: {{school_detail.location}}</p>
<h3 class="h3">Student Details:</h3>
  <!-- students is the related name given in the model with the foreign key -->
  <!-- which connects with the school model -->
  {% for stu in student_detail.students.all %}
    <p>{{stu.name}} who is {{stu.age}} years old</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I have created two links in my school_list.html which opens the respective school detail page and displays the content. 
After opening the details page i am not able to view the student details of the respective school. I checked the files many times but was not able to find out what is the fault. I have attached the image of [No. of students in the school model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNN8Z.png) and [School Details Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qEFZ.png) for reference.

Can anyone help me how to fix this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhabs this school does not have any student.

Comment: Can you (a) properly indent your code; (b) provide relevant deltails of your models; (c) show the URL you passed; and (d) ensure that there are related students to your `School`?

Comment: I have edited the question with relevant details and have checked there are student details present in the database

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a typo in the related name of your `Student` model: The related name you put in there is "stduents" but in your template you are using "students".

Secondly, you are using the related name on the wrong (or non existing) model in your template: Change

```
{% for stu in student_detail.students.all %}
```

to

```
{% for stu in school_detail.students.all %}
```

in your template.